# What functionalities that RxJS provide for Angular2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is some [references](https://github.com/angular/angular/search?p=1&q=rxjs&utf8=%E2%9C%93) of RxJS in the Angular2 project. What is RxJS being used for in Angular2?

Comment: Http, EventEmitter, AsyncPipe supports both Promises and Observables, and there are plans of supporting the syntax [`@ObserveChild`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062#issuecomment-152360414) (that would be basically an EventEmitter) or similar (that is an awesome idea btw). That's all I can remember of now.

Comment: Looking at the code, I see that **EventEmitter** is extending **Subject** which is from RxJS. You may move your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of what angular2 uses RxJS for

- Http (for example its [`get`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L28) method returns an `Observable`)
- [EventEmitter](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/facade/async.ts#L99) (like you said, extends from `Subject`)
- [AsyncPipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L79) which supports `Promise`, `Observable` or `EventEmitter`.
- QueryList's [`changes`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/query_list.ts#L34) method returns an `EventEmitter`. **Update**
- [NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5020) which implements [`Validator`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/validators.ts#L26) and overrides the method `validate` to return either a `Promise` or an `Observable`. **Update**

**Note about NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS**

`NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` doesn't use `Observable` directly, it doesn't subscribe to them but converts them to `Promises`, in any case, `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` still accepts `Observables`. Look at line [#104](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/validators.ts#L104) in `validators.ts`.

Thanks to @przemcio for the observation.

**Not yet implemented / In conversation**

- [ObserveChild](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062#issuecomment-152360414) which would return an `EventEmitter`.
- [ObserveChildren](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5467) **Update**

**Note**

They are working on bundle RxJS with the bare operators, see issue [#5288](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5288). The idea is to distribute angular2 with the minimal required operators and make the user to provide the rest of them.

**Note update**

Like I was told [here](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=5652628ba051fea3424336f8) and [here](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=56526a6254ba2ca242611aab) (I had a problem with importing `Subject`) they're working on removing completely `Subject`, so from core we would be able to import only `Observable`, everything else should be provided by the developer.

*PS*

I can't think of any other, if I remember of something else I'll update the answer.

Comment: Are you sure about that async validators? I saw in alpha-45 only Promises and any Observable.

Comment: @przemcio sorry, I didn't really understand your question.

Comment: I saw in code that validator can only return Promises and NOT observables.

Comment: @przemcio you are right, but look this [line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/validators.ts#L104), it does accept Observables, but converts them to Promises. The question was where angular2 uses RxJS and this uses them but not directly. I will add a note about that one in case is confusing.