# Is Angular5 using rxjs at http://reactivex.io/rxjs or https://angular.io/guide/rx-library?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When searching for answers to Angular questions about RxJS (reactive programming), I sometimes end up on the http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ website, and sometimes in the Angular IO documentation (e.g., https://angular.io/guide/rx-library).

Are these the *same*?  I think they are but wanted to ask and make sure.

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) refer to the [RxJS Docs http://reactivex.io/rxjs/](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) in the first paragraph describing what the RxJS library is.

Being new to Angular, and not having heard of the RxJS library before, I thought that Angular had it's own implementation of RxJS and that RxJS was just a specification, but upon examining the package.json file I can that RxJS under the @angular/ namespace (it is just `npm install rxjs`) and so it doesn't appear to me (anymore) that Angular is implementing it's own version of RxJs.

Some of my confusion was from the Angular docs describing RxJS (so I thought RxJS was part of Angular), but Angular docs also referred to the RxJS library.  So which is it.  That's why I wrote this question.

**Please confirm that the RxJS package being described by Angular at https://angular.io/guide/rx-library is the same as the one at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/? And not a custom version/Angular of it.**

If it matters, I'm using @angular/core version 5.2.9, and rxjs version 5.5.8.

Some other links I found when researching this

- [What functionalities that RxJS provide for Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860374/what-functionalities-that-rxjs-provide-for-angular2)
- [Angular 2 and RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053095/angular-2-and-rxjs)
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS
- https://auth0.com/blog/making-use-of-rxjs-angular/
- [Angular 2 - Rxjs Intelligent with VS 2015 update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078602/angular-2-rxjs-intelligent-with-vs-2015-update-3)
- [Import Rxjs in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919527/import-rxjs-in-angular2)

Comment: The link **API Documentation (WIP)** at the top of the readme on the GitHub repo points to http://reactivex.io/rxjs/

Comment: Just to answer this question: yes, Angular uses that package as a dependency. rxjs has existed indepdenrly of Angular, but it sort of became "big" because of Angular. It's still a separately maintained project, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out yourself create a new project

Install the desired CLI version.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Next create a new project

```
ng new myProject --skip-install
```

Now check the `package.json`

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is the same. Angular uses the RXJS package as dependency.